# Copying data from a model field to another field without losing data

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to copy data and add it to another field without lose or corrupt data. after that delete old field and continue with new field. Im using postgresql and when i try this connection with fields to copy data i get e.300 and e.307 error as i see on internet this problem cause by wrong foreign key usage and caused by same problem.

POST MODEL

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('user.CustomUser', verbose_name='Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/images")
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Publishing Date', auto_now_add=True)
```

COMMENT MODEL

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey('post.Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name')
    # user = models.ForeignKey('self.user', related_name='comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm currently trying to copy `name` field to `user` field and when makemigrate i get e.307 and e.300 errors

ERRORS:

```
post.Comment.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'self.user', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

post.Comment.user:(fields.E307) The field post.Comment.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'self.user', but app 'self' isn't installed.
```

Thanks for anyone who try to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried changing `self.user` to `user.CustomUser` as you did in your `Post` model?